# Word for "does not exist"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for the text within quotation marks in the citation below?

> All such statements [entity doesn’t exist] are casual short-hand for a more elaborate and technical statement: “this alleged entity has no place in any scientific equations, plays no role in any scientific explanations, cannot be used to predict any events, does not describe any thing or force that has yet been detected, and there are no models of the universe in which its presence is either required, productive, or useful.”

Comment: _Imaginary_ is one such; _spiritual_ is another. Depends on what Entity they're talking about.

Comment: I think imaginary is rather unsuitable due to imaginary numbers having a real impact on our understanding (and thus have a productive property) in trigonometry and analysis. Spiritual fits, but are all non-existing entities spiritual?

Comment: Er, are you really asking for a single word to convey what has taken more than fifty to express in "this alleged entity ... productive, or useful."?

Comment: The more elaborate and technical description does not sound anything like “does not exist” to me. It sounds much more like something along the lines of _unfounded_. Quite apart from that, “All such statements [entity doesn’t exist]” makes absolutely no grammatical sense to me—I cannot fathom what the resulting phrasing would be once you have found the word you’re looking for.

Comment: Being kicked in the butt five times is not imaginary, but _five_ is. "Imaginary" numbers are no more imaginary than "real" numbers, or any numbers; all of them were invented by people and don't exist in the physical world where we exist. Don't confuse math with science; science has data, and never proves anything, while math has no data and therefore can prove abstract theorems.

Comment: Background reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontolology and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology

Comment: As implied by John's links, this question doesn't really have any future. Obviously English allows the possibility of *"X does not exist"*, and millions of people have died fighting over versions of it (where *X=someone's god, nation, philosophical ideal, etc.*). The mere fact that X can be *named* gives it some kind of existence, so all variants of "does not exist" just net down to ways of saying "is not acceptable to me".

Comment: @JohnLawler I think the comma qualifies as an AND operator, meaning that if any of the statements are false, so is the entire entity's status as described false. I think mathematics would violate "no --- is either required, productive, or useful".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> . . . this alleged entity has no place in any scientific equations, plays no role in any scientific explanations. . . .

*[Sciosophy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sciosophy)*: supposed knowledge of natural or supernatural phenomena or forces, usually based on tradition, as astrology or phrenology.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that OED apparently has no entry for this or any close variants thereof.

Answer (score 9):

The word you are probably after is *nonexistent*.

If the thing used to exist but no longer does, then you could also use *nonextant*, although that doesn't seem to be that case in your example.

Answer (score 1):

I’d go with [*phantom*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phantom), as it can be applied as both a noun or an adjective.